# Is there an easy way to automate the process of retrieving stock data from yahoo?

Tags: python, dataframe, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I've been trying to automate the process of retrieving data so it will be much faster. Rather than doing this:

```
#Technology

apple= yf.Ticker("aapl")
microsoft= yf.Ticker("msft")
nvidea=yf.Ticker("nvda")

#Apple
appl = apple.history(start=start_date,end=str(end_date))
appl = appl[["Close"]]

#Microsoft
msft = microsoft.history(start=start_date,end=str(end_date))
msft = msft[["Close"]]

#Nvidea
nvda= nvidea.history(start=start_date,end=str(end_date))
nvda = nvda[["Close"]]

df_tech= appl.merge(msft,on='Date').merge(nvda,on='Date')
df_tech.rename(columns={'Close_x':'Apple','Close_y':'Microsoft', 'Close':'Nvidea' }, inplace=True)
```

I wanted to do something more like this:

```
#Technology

apple= yf.Ticker("aapl")
microsoft= yf.Ticker("msft")
nvidea=yf.Ticker("nvda")

tech_list=[apple,microsoft,nvidea]
ticker_list=['appl','msft','nvda']

for (i,j) in (tech_list,ticker_list):
    j=i.history(start=start_date,end=str(end_date))
    j=j[["Close"]]
```

Could somebody help me? It keeps appearing the error that says "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: Try this: `df = yf.download(ticker_list, start=start_date, end=end_date)[['Close']]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this too, this works:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()

start_date = (current_date - timedelta(7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = current_date
ticker_list = ["0P0000TKZK.L","shel.l", "bp.l" ]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in ticker_list:
  
    item = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)
    df = pd.concat([df, item])
       
print(df)

df.to_csv("test_ouput.csv")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).